# How to sort/order FCE's in the backend on the "New content element" wizard

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux

how can I sort/order the FCE in the list on the "New content element" Wizard in TYPO3?
I have found the CacheFramework entry where the TSconfig comes from, but I dont't know how I can change the sorting of the FCE's. My wizardTab is "Content-Elements".

`cf_fluidcontent` entity contains:

```
...
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.Content-Elements {
                header = Content-Elements
                show = buz,foo,bar
                position = 0
                key = test_template
}
```

regards

Kay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here
https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent/issues/181

so you can use the Flux-Form to sort the Elements

```
<flux:form id="foo"
               options="{
               Fluidcontent: {sorting: 101},
               icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/Foo.png\')}',
               group: 'My FCE'
               }"
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

The order depends on the order in which the items are added to `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.Content-Elements.elements`.

`mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.Content-Elements.show` does not specify the order.

(TYPO3 6.2.14)